# Movie about man obsessed with model trains and his wife who electrocutes him and buries him in the model

Tags: identify-this-movie

This a probably an episode of Twilight zone or Tales of the unexpected, Alfred Hitchcock presents or similar series. Definitely from 80's-90's. Color, not black and white.

There was this man that was obsessed with making model trains and railways. His neglected wife was growing more and more jealous of this hobby until she decided to pick it up, too. This started a rivalty between the two. Finally the wife electrocuted the husband and buried him inside a huge landscape railway model. When the police arrived they started playing with the trains and the train got stuck in a tunnel. When they reached for it, they pulled out husbands hand. At the end the wife was in a (the) train and entered a tunnel.

Do you know this movie/episode?

Edit: So far it's not "Track 29", nor "So You Want a Model Railroad"

Comment: I gues I've seen this in the 80ies on TV (Germany)... I remember that she connected his metal-chair to electricity, but then unplugs it. He finds the plug, thinks it's part of the model train and re-plugs it. Then we see how he is about to sit down and the camera switches to her in the kitchen, a pan in her hand and we hear the fring of the food/the guy...

Comment: Oh, and I think, she gets mad in the end, because the landscape she's driving through in a train, resembles the one she created around her husbands corpse

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could be the German TV-movie "[Liebe, Tod und Eisenbahn](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097749/?ref_=nv_sr_1)" from **1989**.
It is also known as "Amor, Muerte y Trenes" and seemed to be shown in Argentina.

Here is a summary from an IMDB-user:

> a TV-thriller about the love of a man for his miniature-trains. Whole the house gets part of it, up to his wife gets enough of it and intends to electrocute him on his chrome-tubed chair by cut plugs of the electrical coffee mill in connection with the 'traintrafo' which will be activated by starting the train system. The tension is rising when Heiner Lauterbach's 'trainmates' miss him for longer time not being at home and looking for research. The corps of her dead husband she buried in the immense mountain of paper-maché of the new added 'mountain' in the alps-look-a-like landscape of the train complex. The mini-train landscape turns into live-action - after metamorphosis of the Märklin- and Faller objects - into real life

(Heiner Lauterbach is the actor of the husband)

And here is the scene were the wife recognisces that she is trapped in the landscape, she burried her husband in:

Comment: OMG! @Marzipanherz, that's it!!! I can't believe it, I've been looking for it for the past 5 years! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Elitsa I'm glad I could help! I was looking for this myself. They key was, not to google it in English, but German.

Comment: Yes, probably, but I wasn't sure of the original language. I probably watched it dubbed. I was almost sure it's a part from Twilight zone or similar series, because it sounds like it is and they used to show a lot of these on our national TV back in the 90s. Although there was this little doubt that it might be from any of the european countries, too.

Answer (score 3):

"Track 29"(1988)?
It starred Theresa Russell, Gary Oldman, and Christopher Lloyd. Here is the plot description from Wikipedia:

"The childless wife of a small town doctor in North Carolina, tired of his spending too much time playing with his model trains and her empty life, meets a young British hitchhiker in a café. She starts thinking he might be the baby she was made to give up for adoption when she was a schoolgirl of 15. In her fantasies, as the two start getting to know each other, she finds she has not only the child she has always missed but also a potentially virile lover. He for his part starts wanting to harm her husband, who in fact is planning to leave her for a nurse he loves."

Here is a trailer.

Comment: In what way does this meet the description given in the question other than *model trains*?

Comment: None, I guess. There must be dozens of movies with this plot, huh?

Comment: Thought it was a good guess, in color, from the '80s, obsession with model trains. Why all the down votes?

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context...not guesses. **Explain why your answer is right**, ideally with citations.

Comment: I did, I cited the plot from Wikipedia. The trailer as well, I've seen lots of bad guesses on here that don't get down voted and have no citations.  I think I've had enough correct answers on here and have established myself somewhat, I guess this just hurts because I've never been down voted like this.Geeeeze!

Comment: I don't know if this matter, but I for one think it's a good guess.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion for Track 29 - that was the first movie I found based on the description, but after I watched the trailer I saw it's not it. It's not "So You Want a Model Railroad" - episode from The Joe MacDoakes collection form 1955 either.

Comment: Sorry elitsa, hope you find it, and sorry to the poor souls out there for my horrible guess, because I know if I look at their old answers I probably won't find ANY guesses, right?